# Metal API: Changing Texture indices on the fly

Tags: glsl, metal

I did a glsl -> metal parser that works pretty well if the glsl code is not using very old features.

The biggest issue I'm facing is when a glsl code does **not** explicitly define a texture binding location, like:

```
uniform layout(binding = 0) sampler2D myTexture; // this is fine
uniform sampler2D myTexture2;  // this is the problem
```

In metal you have to define a texture index on compile time. While in glsl you are allowed to specify (and change) it on run-time.

I believe this is not possible, specially because I can't find it on the spec, but does anyone know if it's possible to specify (or change) a texture index of a metal shader on the fly in CPU side?

```
texture2d < half > myTexture[[ texture(IDX) ]]  // where IDX is not constexpr?
```

Comment: Most options are going to entail recompiling the shader: function constants and textual substitution are two possibilities, but it seems you want to avoid these. In that case, you could try using [argument buffers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/buffers/about_argument_buffers?language=objc), which remove the requirement to explicitly allocate a texture argument slot for each texture, though of course they come with their own set of caveats.

Comment: Thanks for the help Warren! But if I understood correctly I still need to specify a texture binding slot (in metal I believe it's called index) to the argument buffer encoder, meaning that if I want to access it on the shader I need to use [[ id(IDX)  ]]; and send IDX using [encoder setTexture:myTex atIndex:IDX];. This would be fine just if I could change IDX on run-time or maybe not use indices and use something else that can be changed on run-time

Comment: No; you still have to allocate a _buffer_ binding slot for the argument buffer itself, and the argument buffer layout is static, and you do encode resources into the argument buffer by index on the CPU side, but you don't have to specify an index _inside the shader_; you just access the texture as a member of the argument buffer struct.

Comment: I understand I need to specify a binding slot for the argument buffer, but without a texture index how does the API know which texture to bind to the argument buffer (when I have multiple textures in the same argument buffer, for example)? When I bind a texture (using setTexture) I must provide a texture index (binding slot) and afaik this index must align with one provided within the shader using [[id()]]. Can you give me a code example of an index not being specified within the shader?

Comment: The `id` attributes in the shader on the members of an argument buffer struct are optional. If you don't provide them, you can use the `reflection` parameter of `newArgumentEncoderWithBufferIndex:...` to get the list of automatically allocated binding indices.

Comment: I see, I thought reflection was just output for CPU to read (debugging and stuff), if I change reflection will it reflect back in the the argument encoder?

Comment: No, reflection is immutable. Can you give an example of exactly which OpenGL feature(s) you're trying to emulate? I would've though using reflection to be analogous to using `glGetUniformLocation` to look up uniforms that otherwise lack an explicit binding location.

Comment: Yes reflection is analogous to `glGetUniformLocation` but what I need is a metal equivalent to `glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation("MyTex"), index)` that code sets the texture binding location (index) in run-time from CPU side